# Floating point inverse binary representation

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++14, ieee-754

I'm confused with the following pieces of code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(10.0f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(-10.0f) << std::endl;

    float x = 10.0f;
    std::bitset<32> bsx(x);
    float y = -10.0f;
    std::bitset<32> bsy(y);
    std::cout << bsx << std::endl;
    std::cout << bsy << std::endl;
}
```

the second one just (yes, it's just a truncated first one):

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(10.0f) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(-10.0f) << std::endl;
}
```

I'm getting the following outputs:
the 1st one:

```
00000000000000000000000000001010
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000001010
11111111111111111111111111110110
```

the 2nd:

```
00000000000000000000000000001010
00000000000000010010000001101000
```

The system is Clang 4.0.0 on macOS Sierra (10.12.3), floats are 32-bits here as I know.

(Compiled with `g++ -pedantic -std=c++14`.)

The only thing I'm aware of for floating-point numbers is the IEEE-754, which states there should be a separate sign bit. The last output of the first program seems to be using two's complement...

And the other ones are just totally confusing.. all zeros and somewhat random output, even with the same code, just truncated..

What do I misunderstand? Am I getting undefined behaviour somewhere in code? Don't understand the syntax? Or floats for some reason can't be represented as bitsets?

Comment: `std::bitset` does not have a ctor that takes a float, so you're implicitly converting it

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `std::bitset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not display the binary representation of floating point numbers, no. Because there are no [`std::bitset` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset) that take a floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It works this way:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
inline unsigned U(float f) { return (unsigned&) f; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(U(10.0f)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::bitset<32>(U(-10.0f)) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've added explicit re-reading of value in another format.
The output is

```
01000001001000000000000000000000
11000001001000000000000000000000
```

(Of course, traditional disclaimer for platform specific details shall be placed here.)

UPDATE: there are issues with memory aliasing that causes the converter would be better written (at least for modern GCC and Clang) in the following way:

```
inline unsigned U(float f) {
    unsigned R;
    memcpy(&R, &f, sizeof(R));
    return R;
}
```

modern compilers treat this memcpy() as "bitcast" operator and internally converts it to a proper kind of register moving. Without this, you can meet some weird issues with aliasing.
But, this approach is still worse for ICC, which prefers union of members of different types:

```
inline unsigned U(float f) {
    union {
        unsigned u;
        float f;
    } t;
    t.f = f;
    return t.u;
}
```

There are contradictory opinions on what style of bitcasting is better for different languages and versions, I will not dive into them here.

Comment: Ins't converting negative floats to unsigned (even if refs) not just an implementation defined behavior, but plain undefined behavior according to the standard?

Comment: @ledonter unsigned/signed doesn't matter here because this is memory chunk reinterpretation, so, platform specific issues are the only important.